# Required fields missing in trigger error. Why?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a trigger to add a custom `Milestone__c` object to a `Case` on case creation.

I have assigned values to the two required fields, which are `Case__c` and `Start__c`, but I am still get the following error when I create a `Case`:

> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Case, Start]: [Case, Start]: Trigger.CaseInitialiseMilestones: line 24, column 1

My trigger code is:

```
Trigger CaseInitialiseMilestones on Case (before insert) {

    List<RecordType> caseRTs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType];
    Map<String, Id> rtMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(RecordType rt : caseRTs) {
        rtMap.put(rt.Name, rt.Id);
    }

    List<Milestone__c> NewMilestones = new List<Milestone__c>();

    for(Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if( c.RecordTypeId == rtMap.get('Sales')) {

            DateTime caseCreation = c.CreatedDate;

            Milestone__c MASOverallResolution = new Milestone__c();
            MASOverallResolution.Start__c = caseCreation;
            MASOverallResolution.Case__c = c.Id;

            NewMilestones.add(MASOverallResolution);
        }
    }

    insert NewMilestones;
}
```

I'd be grateful for any explanation of why it is detecting that the required fields haven't been assigned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your trigger on Case is **before** insert. In this context the Id and CreatedDate have not yet been set. Your trigger should operate **after** insert.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure but I think it may be the case that the Case doesn't have values for ID & CreatedDate until **after** the insert.